# Bash: Why are single quotes in my output files replaced with ~@~X and ~@~Y

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, redhat, wsl-2

```
function GetFilespace() {
    echo "Group ${1}"
    # run du -hs on every user in the /data/ directory. Append to a text file
    du -hs /home/group${1}/data/* >> /home/group1/data/user/stats/filespace_used_individual_${1}.txt
    echo "Done with group ${1}"
}

# Loop through the 4 user groups we have
for GROUP in group1 group2 group3 backup1
do
    # Launch GetFilespace function and append stderr output to a text file
    GetFilespace $GROUP 2>> /home/group1/data/user/stats/permission_denied_${GROUP}.txt &
done
```

I use a code similar to what I have posted above to get stats about individual file space usage and file size for several storage systems where I work. The function `GetFilespace()`  gathers the size of our users individual directories, and I collect stderr output with `2>>` to track which specific files are missing their group read/execution permissions.

Normally when I run this code my stderr output files have lines that look like **fig A** below (censored for privacy). From this I collect the users name and send them a full path to their offending files so they can resolve the issue.

**Figure A**
[image]

However, when I ran my script this week my script that handles user permission issues stopped working. Checking one of the stderr files I found that all single quotes were replaced by `~@~X` and `~@~Y` at the beginning and end of the paths respectively (**fig B**).

**Figure B**
[image]

I checked back through my archived stats and I have no history of this happening before, nor have I been able to find information online. **Could anyone explain what is happening to me, and how to resolve the issue?**

Thank you!

Comment: At a glance, you may be dealing with smart quotes here? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090225-00/?p=19033

Comment: Also check your script with https://shellcheck.net/ as it is missing proper quoting of variable expansion. Fix all issues it reveals to you.

Comment: @LéaGris Thank you for that bash spellchecker! The quotes around variables have always confused me since everything usually seems to work. But even after adding that I noticed no difference in the results. Still getting the `~@~X` and `~@~Y`.

Comment: @Erwin I am unsure that this is the cause. For one I am working on Linux not Windows. And then additionally I haven't found any literature that related the characters I am seeing to smart quotes, though to be fair I haven't found anything at all about the character I am seeing so I could still be wrong!!